# Rabbit MQ connection limit?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am working on the messaging framework that listem and publish to the Rabbitmqserver in java 
following is the code

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
     factory.setHost(hostName);
     factory.setPort(portNumber);
     factory.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);
     factory.setUsername(username);
     factory.setPassword(password);
     return factory.newConnection();
```

Is there any limit on how many connection I could make ? I am not able to find our any limit in the rabbit documentation . when i try to make more than 137 connection it looks like it does not work. I am not able to find ny error in the Rabbitmq logs or in the application logs.when I try to debug it looks like last line just wait. my next step to go and figure out what is going on in the RABBITMQ java client code.

Any help or direction would be helpful and greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's possible to view the max and and see how close you are to hitting it via the management console.  The 'Overview' tab lists File Descriptors in use/max, and Socket Descriptors in use/max.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so it looks like my Rabbitmq server ras running out of socket and it dosn't throw an error just wait for another connection to be free. I was using Mac OS where default ulimit is 256 it ends up giving 156 file handlers and 138 connection. all i did is just changes the ulimit to the 1024.

Comment: You are correct your ulimit was too low and that was causing the problem.  If you use the management plugin and view it through a browser the overview tab will give you some information about how much of the system resources it is using and how much more you can use.

Comment: Thanks Rob I tried to use the management plugin but it looks like it is not available for version 2.3.1 ? not sure can I download and install it for this version but I ended up seeing the start up logs. Thanks a lot